# Minimize my code with My TOOLBAR and SCREEN MANAGER

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I try to reduce my code. I'm using kivyMD. I created a MDToolbar with a menu into a MDNavigationLayout. I also created differents screen using ScreenManager.

Like : Home, Profile, Contact.

The problem is that I copy/paste all my code of the MDToolbar into each screen in my kv file.

But I'd like to only have a 'Header' for all my screen. And it's not that easy for me to read the doc... I didn't find what I want.

So, I share the code with you :

Python code :

```
class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ProfilScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ContactScreen(Screen):
    pass

sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='home'))
sm.add_widget(ProfilScreen(name='profil'))
sm.add_widget(ContactScreen(name='contact'))



class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Red'
        screen = Builder.load_string(navigation_helper)
        return screen

    def nav_drawer(self):
        pass

DemoApp().run()
```

KV code :

```
ScreenManager:
    HomeScreen:
    ProfilScreen:
    ContactScreen:


<HomeScreen>:
    name: 'home'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 35

        MDLabel:
            text: "My Content"

    Screen:
        MDNavigationLayout:
            ScreenManager:
                Screen:
                    BoxLayout:
                        orientation: 'vertical'

                        MDToolbar:
                            title: 'Demo Application'
                            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('toggle')]]
                            elevation: 10
                        Widget:
                
        
            MDNavigationDrawer:
                id: nav_drawer
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    spacing: '8dp'
                    padding: '8dp'

                    Image:
                        source: 'img\logo.png'
                        size_hint: .5, .5
                        pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'Le Réseau Foncier'
                        font_style: 'Subtitle1'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.texture_size[1]

                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'contact@lereseaufoncier.fr'
                        font_style: 'Caption'
                        size_hint_y: None
                        height: self.texture_size[1]

                    ScrollView:
                        MDList:

                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: 'Home'
                                on_press: root.manager.current= 'home'

                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: 'home'
                                    on_press: root.manager.current= 'home'

                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: 'Profile'
                                on_press: root.manager.current= 'profil'

                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: 'android'
                                    on_press: root.manager.current= 'profil'
                            
                            OneLineIconListItem:
                                text: 'Contact'
                                on_press: root.manager.current= 'contact'

                                IconLeftWidget:
                                    icon: 'phone'
                                    on_press: root.manager.current= 'contact'
```

This is the same code for  and .

I hope someone can help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re, so I find the solution :

Here, all the code :

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window


Window.size = (800, 800)

navigation_helper = """



Screen:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            id: title_bar
            title: 'Demo Application'
            left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state('toggle')]]
            elevation: 10
            height:'50dp'
        Widget:


    MDNavigationLayout:

        ScreenManager:
            id: scr
        
            MDScreen:
                name: 'home'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'Some home text'
                
                
            MDScreen:
                name: 'profil'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'Some profil text'

            MDScreen:
                name: 'contact'
                BoxLayout:
                    orientation: 'vertical'

                    MDLabel:
                        text: 'Some contact text'

    
        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
        
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                spacing: '8dp'
                padding: '8dp'

                Image:
                    source: 'img\logo.png'
                    size_hint: .5, .5
                    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5}

                MDLabel:
                    text: 'Le Réseau Foncier'
                    font_style: 'Subtitle1'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]

                MDLabel:
                    text: 'contact@lereseaufoncier.fr'
                    font_style: 'Caption'
                    size_hint_y: None
                    height: self.texture_size[1]

                ScrollView:
                    MDList:

                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: 'Home'
                            on_press: scr.current= 'home'

                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: 'home'
                                on_press: scr.current= 'home'

                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: 'Profile'
                            on_press: scr.current= 'profil'

                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: 'android'
                                on_press: scr.current= 'profil'
                        
                        OneLineIconListItem:
                            text: 'Contact'
                            on_press: scr.current= 'contact'

                            IconLeftWidget:
                                icon: 'phone'
                                on_press: scr.currentt= 'contact'



            
"""


class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'Red'
        screen = Builder.load_string(navigation_helper)
        return screen

    def nav_drawer(self):
        pass

DemoApp().run()
```

Have a nice day.